# How can I run kile after updating to texlive 2012 on ubuntu 12.04 (for beginners)

Tags: 12.04, installation, latex

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and Kile 2.1.0. After updating texlive from 2009 to 2012 kile did not work again. As mentioned here, I tried this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-base
```

it did not change my error message.

The error when I start kile is:

```
The file /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls could not be loaded
This folder does not exist anymore.
```

So, somehow a have to change the system settings. But where?

Typing `latex -v` in kile gives me following result:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.46
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.3.4
Compiled with poppler version 0.18.4
```

I saw some hints changing this, but since I am new I did not understand how to implement theme on my computer. Furthermore /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux does also not exist.

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

The style file you are looking for is shipped with [texlive-latex-recommended](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/texlive-latex-recommended)

Just install it with

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```

There is no need to add a *ppa* for that.

That problem shows up quite regularly with Ubuntu/Debian since the various cls files are distributed in useful (smaller than several GB) packages.

You can always try to go to [packages.ubuntu.com -> Search the contents of packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents) if you are looking for a package containing a file.

Friends of the command line might check out the `apt-file` tool (since `dpkg -S` only looks for already installed packages).